# Get distinct difference of text column between rows with grouping column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame ordered by `id` and `time` there is a column with text for each  row I would like to get the unique difference between the rows for two scenarios by `id`:

1. the text in the current row compared to the previous row and the # of distinct differences
2. the text in the current row compared to all previous rows and the # of distinct differences

The sample data below has the input columns and my desired ouput columns 4:7. I would prefer a tidyverse solution but any would work. TIA

*EDIT* Data is cleaner now

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), time = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), input = c("Item 1,Item 2,Item 3,Item 4", 
"Item 1,Item 3,Item 5", "Item 1,Item 2,Item 3,Item 4", "Item 7,Item 4,Item 8", 
"Item 12,Item 20,Item 30", "Item 12,Item 20,Item 30,Item 4,Item 8", 
"A,B,C,D", "C,D,E,F", "A,B,C,D,E,F"), new_items = c(NA, "Item 5", 
"Item 2, Item 4", NA, "Item 12,Item 20,Item 30", "Item 4, Item 8", 
NA, "E,F", "A,B"), num_of_new_items = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 
2, 2), new_items_overall = c(NA, "Item 5", NA, NA, "Item 12,Item 20,Item 30", 
NA, NA, "E, F", NA), num_of_new_items_overall = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 0, 2, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Trying to have the sample as similar as possible to my actual data that is the result of a collect_set sql query. I'll remove the  extra text and assume my first step would be a regular expression to get rid of it.

Comment: I cleaned up the data

Comment: Could you write up your desired output for this example data? Is "the current row", the row with the greatest time value?

Comment: The desired output is the last 4 columns.  The data is in order  so current row is just  the rows in order per id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - I designated your dataframe as `df`, and I left in a step to clean up the gunky characters if you end up needing it (it will run fine on your updated data). I first copied columns 1-3 into a new `df2`, and went from there (using `dplyr` and `purrr` functions):

```
df2 <- df[1:3]
df2
# clean up ugly extra characters, if necessary, to leave item names separated by commas list
df2 <- mutate(df2, input=str_replace_all(input, '[\\[\\\\\"\\]]', '')) %>% print()
# convert each input string into a list of strings, separating by commas
df2 <- mutate(df2, input_list = map(input, function(x) str_split(x, ',')[[1]]),
              input_list_all = input_list) %>% print()
# group by ID and create "rolling" list of all unique input items in the group
df2 <- group_by(df2, id) %>% 
  mutate(input_list_all = accumulate(input_list_all, .dir='forward', function(x, y)
    c(x, y) %>% unique()
  ))
# compare each input row to the row before - if there is no previous row, return NULL
df2 <- mutate(df2, new_items = map2(input_list, lag(input_list, n=1), function(x, y) {
  if(is.null(y)) return(NULL)
  else return(setdiff(x, y))
}))
# count new items
df2 <- mutate(df2, num_of_new_items=map_int(new_items, length)) %>% print()
# compare each input row to all previous rows
df2 <- mutate(df2, new_items_overall = map2(input_list, lag(input_list_all, n=1), function(x, y) {
  if(is.null(y)) return(NULL)
  else return(setdiff(x, y))
})) %>% print()
# count overall new items
df2 <- mutate(df2, num_of_new_items_overall=map_int(new_items_overall, length)) %>% print()
# clean up real nice - get rid of unneeded columns, convert lists to comma-separated strings
df2 <- select(df2, -c(input_list:input_list_all)) %>% 
  mutate(new_items = map_chr(new_items, function(x) paste(x, collapse=',')),
         new_items_overall = map_chr(new_items_overall, function(x) paste(x, collapse=',')))
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 7
# Groups:   id [3]
     id  time input                         new_items num_of_new_items new_items_overall num_of_new_items_ove…¹
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                         <chr>                <int> <chr>                              <int>
1     1     1 Item 1,Item 2,Item 3,Item 4   ""                       0 ""                                     0
2     1     2 Item 1,Item 3,Item 5          "Item 5"                 1 "Item 5"                               1
3     1     3 Item 1,Item 2,Item 3,Item 4   "Item 2,…                2 ""                                     0
4     2     1 Item 7,Item 4,Item 8          ""                       0 ""                                     0
5     2     2 Item 12,Item 20,Item 30       "Item 12…                3 "Item 12,Item 20…                      3
6     2     3 Item 12,Item 20,Item 30,Item… "Item 4,…                2 ""                                     0
7     3     1 A,B,C,D                       ""                       0 ""                                     0
8     3     2 C,D,E,F                       "E,F"                    2 "E,F"                                  2
9     3     3 A,B,C,D,E,F                   "A,B"                    2 ""                                     0
# ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​num_of_new_items_overall
```

The only thing that isn't perfect is that it doesn't return NA where there are no new values, instead you get an empty string. But you can work around that.

Comment: Works great!  My actual data  had some extra whitespace so I had to add a step to clean up the whitespace. Thanks